# sails-redis: increment attributes values

Tags: redis, sails.js, sails-redis

I'd like to use [sails-redis](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis) to track all kinds of events.

Therefore I need the ability to increment model attributes in a performant way.

I already found the [`Model.native`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis/blob/master/lib/adapter.js#L215-L225) function, wich allows me to access the native redis methods.

But since [sails-redis](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis) is based on Strings and not on Hashes I can not use any native increment methods (so far i know).

Is there any clean and performant way to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The thing [sails-redis](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis) does is to create a database with CRUD methods by using redis key-value-store based on strings.

Therefore do not see [sails-redis](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis) as an wrapper for redis. Forget about that. It is just another database which almost has nothing to do with redis.

> Use the right tool for the right job!

I you have a job like event tracking where you want to use Redis because of it's speed use [node-redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and implement it yourself. [sails-redis](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis) is just not made for such things.

I simply created a new [service](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/Services/Services.md) and used [node-redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). There might be a more elegant way, but mines works and improved performance a hole lot.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis/issues/34

Comment: I know the comment comes late for the thread, but I encountered the same kind of 'problem' now and I'm also thinking of abandoning sails-redis in favor of a wrapper service over node-redis. Considering this why should one use sails-redis at all? If it creates a classic no sql database on top of redis and you lose the performance bonus isn't it better to go with something like mongo and sails-mongo?